# In Selenium Grid how & where multiple scripts get executed?

Tags: selenium-grid

In Selenium Grid suppose I have 4 scripts and I have to run 2 at one node 
and 2 at another. Where and how these all scripts run on hub?
Is it simultaneously or one by one?

Answer (score 0):

Questions isn't very clear on what the intent is.

In General, Each test that is given to HUB should specify the desired capabilities of a machine on which test should be run.  Example:  If one has 4 scripts and wants to run 2 on Windows with Firefox and another 2 on Max with Safari then script should be creating the RemoteWebDriver(Url, DesiredCapabilities).